# How to implement a Navbar Dropdown Hover in Bootstrap v4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a bit confused on the new bootstrap version since they changed dropdown menus to divs:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Do you guys have any idea to get a hover dropdown in the Dropdown link in that snippet without adding additional script code (only css and script from bootstrap)? I already saw the bootstrap css classes and I can't relate with the ones in bootstrap V3 (I accomplish this without adding jquery in V3).

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and came up with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357143/how-to-delay-the-removal-of-a-class-for-a-dropdown-mega-menu-bootstrap-4

Comment: Hover menu's are a bad idea and a bad UI/UX specially if you're planning for mobile

Answer (score 179, accepted):

**Simple, CSS only** solution:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

When clicked, it will still get the class `show` toggled to it (and will remain open when no longer hovered).

---

To get around this ***properly*** is to use events and properties reserved to pointer based devices: jQuery's `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and `:hover`. Should work smoothly, intuitively, while not interfering ***at all*** with how the dropdown works on touch based devices. Try it out, let me know if it works for you:

Complete **jQuery solution** (*touch* untouched):

Pre v4.1.2 solution (***deprecated***):

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', function (e) {
  var _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown')
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') _d.addClass('show')
  setTimeout(function () {
    _d.toggleClass('show', _d.is(':hover'))
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded', _d.is(':hover'))
  }, 300)
})
```

Demo:

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', function (e) {
  var _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown')
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') _d.addClass('show')
  setTimeout(function () {
    _d.toggleClass('show', _d.is(':hover'))
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded', _d.is(':hover'))
  }, 300)
})

/* this is not needed, just prevents page reload when a dd link is clicked */
$('.dropdown a').on('click tap', (e) => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href>Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

[v4.1.2 shiplist](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26423) introduced [this change](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/26756) to how dropdowns work, making the solution above no longer work.
Here's the ***up to date*** solution for having the dropdown open on hover in **v4.1.2** and above:

```js
function toggleDropdown(e) {
  const _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown'),
    _m = $('.dropdown-menu', _d)
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      const shouldOpen = e.type !== 'click' && _d.is(':hover')
      _m.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen)
      _d.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen)
      $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded', shouldOpen)
    },
    e.type === 'mouseleave' ? 300 : 0
  )
}

$('body')
  .on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', toggleDropdown)
  .on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', toggleDropdown)
```

Demo:

```js
function toggleDropdown(e) {
  const _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown'),
    _m = $('.dropdown-menu', _d)
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      const shouldOpen = e.type !== 'click' && _d.is(':hover')
      _m.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen)
      _d.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen)
      $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded', shouldOpen)
    },
    e.type === 'mouseleave' ? 300 : 0
  )
}

$('body')
  .on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', toggleDropdown)
  .on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', toggleDropdown)

/* not needed, prevents page reload for SO example on menu link clicked */
$('.dropdown a').on('click tap', (e) => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

*Important note:* If using the jQuery solution, it is important to remove the CSS one (or the dropdown won't close when `.dropdown-toggle` is clicked or when an menu option is clicked).

Comment: Hi thanks for your asnwer, I accomplished that aswell, but if u click the dropmenu "stays". I wouldn't like to use something like "preventdefault", do you know some css trick (remove or add) to get the dropdown not staying on click?

Comment: @Exprove There's is no *clean* CSS way of doing that. Because Bootstrap are using `JavaSript`. Bootstrap dropdowns do not work without `js`. Anyway, I took the time to look into how they do it and I came up with a script that doesn't touch *touch behavior* and provides what you asked for on desktops. Test it out, let me know if you find any trouble with it, I didn't, so far. Willing to improve it, if needed. Might come in handy for many if it's done right.

Comment: Everything works fine, but I really need to get the Dropdown link to work, if I press on the "Dropdown link" it should go to the http://example.com, I just can't accomplish that, I already had a close solution (like yours with jquery). Maybe if I override the click event with jquery might work, but it seems a sloppy solution.

Comment: Use a [`split button`](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns). They are made exactly for that.

Comment: Adding this fixes the gap in the above solution.. .dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: @scottheckel, I added updating `aria-expanded` attribute.

Comment: suppose, there is sub-menu inside dropdown link --> action--> and another action then how to give hover. When hover on action another action hoverable is not show and when hover on another action,  action hoverable in not show.
How to do this. Anyone can help.

Comment: This solution will not work with subnavs that use the dropdown-menu class. When hovering it will show all subnavs at the same time.

Comment: @tao, you're a legend!

Comment: Great solution. A small addition: if the sub menu link goes to an ancher in the page (so for example href="#contact" then on mobile phone, the menu will remain open. So the user will have menu visible over in this case my contact form on the same page.  I added this code to overcome this issue: 
 
 jQuery('.nav-item-close').on('click', function(event){
  $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide')
 });
 
And add class "nav-item-close" to all the "nav-item" where you want to have the behaviour that the menu collapses after a click.

Answer (score 53):

Just Add this simple *css* code in your style-sheet and you are ready to go.

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active {
    /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: this is best answer

Comment: This is not the best answer, unfortunately; it misses toggling a lot of classes and firing events

Comment: plus on collapsed mode you can not toggle the dropdown anymore

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 it works ! Only if you are not looking for event firing events, this can be used !

Comment: This is a great solution, be sure to add some padding bottom to the link to stop the dropdown-menu from closing when moving the cursor from the link to the menu.

Comment: Thank you! This is very important to remove stickiness (stays opened) on click.

Comment: .dropdown-menu {margin:0 !important;}

stop the dropdown-menu from closing when moving to multiple dropdown menu

Comment: Just like to point out for anyone like myself using Bootstrap 5, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

## Bootstrap 4 CSS-only

None of the CSS only answers work entirely. Either the dropdown menu stays open after click, or there is a gap that makes the dropdown menu hide before you can reach the menu links to click.

**Here's the simple CSS only solution:**

```
.navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Remove `data-toggle=dropdown` from the HTML markup to prevent the dropdown staying open in click. Use `mt-0` (margin-top:0) to eliminate the gap above the menu, and make it possible to hover the menu items.

Demo https://www.codeply.com/go/awyU7VTIJf

---

Complete Code:

```
   .navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    } 

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      ..
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: That `mt-0` tip is gold. My dropdown kept disappearing sometimes, sometimes not.

Answer (score 10):

Andrei's "complete" jQuery+CSS solution has the right intent, but it's verbose and still incomplete. Incomplete because while it probably covers all the necessary DOM changes, it's missing the firing of [custom events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events). Verbose because it's wheel-reinventing when Bootstrap already provides the [dropdown() method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#methods), which does everything.

So the correct, DRY solution, which does not rely on the CSS hack often repeated among other answers, is **just jQuery**:

```js
$('body').on('mouseover mouseout', '.dropdown', function () {
  $(this).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: I tend to stay away from `toggle`s on mouse events. If it only misfires once, the dropdown will stay open when not hovered and hide when hovered. Typically one can misfire an enter/leave pointer sequence by scribbling with the cursor over the element. But for proper testing, hover the element, change tab or window and go back to your window with the mouse in another position. Now hover the element.

Comment: pureCSS solution which is described above is more accurate than this.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Oops my choice of mouse events wasn't the best; `mouseover mouseout` seems to fix that issue. Thanks, I'll edit my post.

Comment: @MohammadAyoubKhan A pure CSS solution misses various other behaviors though, which include firing events and toggling certain classes and attributes.

Comment: Worked for me! If you're getting errors, supress them like this `try {
      $(e.target).dropdown('toggle');
  }
  catch(z) { /* just to hide the error */ }`

Comment: Because of the mouseout, my dropdown menu is hiding when hovering on it.

Comment: @SamuelDeBacker You could try explicitly setting the exact effect for each event. Something like this `$('body').on('mouseover', '.dropdown', function(e) { $(e.target).dropdown('show') }).on('mouseout', '.dropdown', function(e) { $(e.target).dropdown('hide') })`

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap's functionality appears to have changed slightly since v4 has been released.  The `.dropdown-menu` item appears to also now get the `.show` class in addition to the `.dropdown`.  I adapted Andrei's answer to also toggle the class on the `.dropdown-menu`.  Note that the CSS is no longer necessary and the HTML is the same except I updated the links to the current versions and the nav class changed to `navbar-expand-md`.

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', function (e) {
    var dropdown = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown');
    var menu = $('.dropdown-menu', dropdown);
    dropdown.addClass('show');
    menu.addClass('show');
    setTimeout(function () {
        dropdown[dropdown.is(':hover') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('show');
        menu[dropdown.is(':hover') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('show');
    }, 300);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had already used and styled a navbar when I was requested to change it to a hover interaction instead, so ended up with this as a fix using jQuery.

```
function bootstrapHoverMenu (bp = 768) {

  // close all dropdowns that are open
    $('body').click( function (e) {
    $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
  });

  // show dropdown for the link clicked
  $('.nav-item').hover(function (e) {
    $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
    if(( $(window).width() >= bp )) {
      $dd = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
      $dd.addClass('show');
    }
  });

  // get href for top level link if clicked and open
  $('.dropdown').click(function (e) {
    if( $(window).width() < bp ) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').css({'display': 'none'});
    }
    $href = $(this).find('.nav-link').attr('href');
    window.open($href, '_self');
  });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
   // when page ready run the fix
   bootstrapHoverMenu();
});
```

Downside is mobile only has top level links.

Comment: i think pureCSS solution is best.

Answer (score 3):

## Bootstrap v4 Solution - jQuery based, but better than a pure css solution

> This ensures that you can still follow top level link clicks and is
> compatible with mobile.

This was built with desktop and mobile in mind. Fell free to wrap the jQuery with a conditional that checks if the window width is greater than 768px.

#### jQuery

```
/** Dropdown on hover */
$(".nav-link.dropdown-toggle").hover( function () {
    // Open up the dropdown
    $(this).removeAttr('data-toggle'); // remove the data-toggle attribute so we can click and follow link
    $(this).parent().addClass('show'); // add the class show to the li parent
    $(this).next().addClass('show'); // add the class show to the dropdown div sibling
}, function () {
    // on mouseout check to see if hovering over the dropdown or the link still
    var isDropdownHovered = $(this).next().filter(":hover").length; // check the dropdown for hover - returns true of false
    var isThisHovered = $(this).filter(":hover").length;  // check the top level item for hover
    if(isDropdownHovered || isThisHovered) {
        // still hovering over the link or the dropdown
    } else {
        // no longer hovering over either - lets remove the 'show' classes
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown'); // put back the data-toggle attr
        $(this).parent().removeClass('show');
        $(this).next().removeClass('show');
    }
});
// Check the dropdown on hover
$(".dropdown-menu").hover( function () {
}, function() {
    var isDropdownHovered = $(this).prev().filter(":hover").length; // check the dropdown for hover - returns true of false
    var isThisHovered= $(this).filter(":hover").length;  // check the top level item for hover
    if(isDropdownHovered || isThisHovered) {
        // do nothing - hovering over the dropdown of the top level link
    } else {
        // get rid of the classes showing it
        $(this).parent().removeClass('show');
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

#### CSS

```
@media(min-width:  768px) {
  .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0; // fixes closing on slow mouse transition
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hoverable dropdown without losing functionality of popper.js for bootstrap 4 only

Javascript

```
$('.dropdown-hoverable').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').click();
}, function(){
    $(this).children('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').click();
});
```

HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-hoverable">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Menu link</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find here the full solution. So, it's my one which **works with Bootstrap v4.4.1 and has the next benefits**:

- A click on the `dropdown-toggle` works as a normal nav link.
- Supports any nesting level of dropdown menus.
- Bootstrap 4 `{show/shown/hide/hidden}.bs.dropdown` events work well.

  ```
   // Toggles a B4 dropdown-menu to a given state.
   const toggleDropdownElement = ($dropdown, shouldOpen = false) => {
     const $dropdownToggle = $dropdown.children('[data-toggle="dropdown"], a');
     const $dropdownMenu = $dropdown.children('.dropdown-menu');

     // Change the dropdown menu. It's similar to B4 Dropdown.show()/.hide(), see /bootstrap/js/src/dropdown.js.
     if (shouldOpen) {
       $dropdown.trigger('show.bs.dropdown');
       $dropdownToggle.attr('aria-expanded', true).focus();
       $dropdownMenu.addClass('show');
       $dropdown.addClass('show').trigger($.Event('shown.bs.dropdown', $dropdownMenu[0]));
     } else {
       $dropdown.trigger('hide.bs.dropdown');
       $dropdownToggle.attr('aria-expanded', false);
       $dropdownMenu.removeClass('show');
       $dropdown.removeClass('show').trigger($.Event('hidden.bs.dropdown', $dropdownMenu[0]));
     }
   };

   // Toggles a B4 dropdown-menu with any nesting level.
   const toggleDropdown = (event) => {
     const $dropdown = $(event.target).closest('.dropdown');
     const $parentDropdownMenu = $dropdown.closest('.dropdown-menu');
     const shouldOpen = event.type !== 'click' && $dropdown.is(':hover');

     // If the dropdown was closed already, break the 'mouseleave' event cascade.
     if (!shouldOpen && !$dropdown.hasClass('show')) return;

     // Change the current dropdown menu (last nested).
     toggleDropdownElement($dropdown, shouldOpen);

     // We have to close the dropdown menu tree if it was a click or the menu was leave at all.
     if (event.type === 'click' || $parentDropdownMenu.length && !$parentDropdownMenu.is(':hover')) {
       $dropdown.parents('.dropdown').each((index, element) => {
         toggleDropdownElement($(element), false);
       });
     }
   };

   if (viewport && viewport.is('>=xl')) {
     $('body')
       .on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', toggleDropdown)
       .on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', toggleDropdown);

     // Disable the default B4's click. Other words, change a dropdown-toggle to a normal nav link.
     $(document).off('click.bs.dropdown', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]');
     $(document).off('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]'); // Not sure about it.
   }
  ```

If you don't use ES6 just change arrow functions to the old function style.

Thanks, @tao for your example, it was helpful for me.

Code related links: [B4 Dropdown Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events), [viewport (Responsive Bootstrap Toolkit)](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit), [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker).

Comment: This one is the best answer. `blur()` is missing though. Is needed to cancel focus on the last dropdown item when hovering on regular non-drop item `$dropdownToggle.attr('aria-expanded', false).blur();`

Answer (score 1):

This solution switches on and off

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // close all dropdowns that are open
  $('body').click(function(e) {
      $('.nav-item.show').removeClass('show');
      //$('.nav-item.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
      $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
  });

  $('.nav-item').click( function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked')
  });

  // show dropdown for the link clicked
  $('.nav-item').hover(function(e) {
      if ($('.nav-item.show').length < 1) {
        $('.nav-item.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
      }
      if ($('.nav-item.clicked').length < 1) {
          $('.nav-item.show').removeClass('show');
          $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
          $dd = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
          $dd.parent().addClass('show');
          $dd.addClass('show');
      }
  });
});</script>
```

To disable the hover for lg sized collapse menus add

```
if(( $(window).width() >= 992 )) {
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solutions not working properly on touch device**

I found that any CSS solutions made the menu stay open on touch devices, they didn't collapse anymore.
So I read the article: https://www.brianshim.com/webtricks/drop-down-menus-on-ios-and-android/ (by Brian Shim)
Very useful! It states that a touch device always first checks the existence of a hover class on an element.
But: by using jQuery .show() you introduce a style attribute (display:block;) that makes the menu open up on first touch. Now the menu has opened without the bootstrap 'show' class. If a user chooses a link from the dropdown menu it works perfectly. But if a user decides to close the menu without using it he has to tap twice to close the menu: At the first tap the original bootstrap 'show' class gets attached so the menu opens up again, at the second tap the menu closes due to normal bootstrap behaviour (removal of 'show' class).

To prevent this I used the article: https://codeburst.io/the-only-way-to-detect-touch-with-javascript-7791a3346685 (by David Gilbertson)

He has some very handy ways of detecting touch or hover devices.

So, combined the two authors with a bit jQuery of my own:

```
$(window).one('mouseover', function(){
      window.USER_CAN_HOVER = true;
      if(USER_CAN_HOVER){
          jQuery('#navbarNavDropdown ul li.dropdown').on("mouseover", function() {
             var $parent = jQuery(this);
             var $dropdown = $parent.children('ul');

             $dropdown.show(200,function() { 
               $parent.mouseleave(function() {
                 var $this = jQuery(this);
                 $this.children('ul').fadeOut(200);
               });
             });
          });
      };
```

});
Check once if a device allows a hover event. If it does, introduce the possibility to hover using .show(). If the device doesn't allow a hover event, the .show() never gets introduced so you get natural bootstrap behaviour on touch device.

Be sure to remove any CSS regarding menu hover classes.

Took me three days :) so I hope it helps some of you.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Remove data-toggle="dropdown" attribute (so click will not open dropdown menu)**

**2. Add :hover pseudo-class to show dropdown-menu**

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

all I am working with bootstrap 5, above solutions were looking big I just removed `data-bs-toggle='dropdown'`because it was blocking the parent link to navigate and toggling script to open the dropdown on click.

And added CSS

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    // removes the gap so it doesn't close ;
}
```

Works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this simply just work with bootstrap 4, i adding in inline but you always can bind event from script.

```
  <a 
onmouseover="$('#navbarDropdownMenuLink').dropdown('toggle')"
class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" 
href="http://example.com" 
id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" 
data-toggle="dropdown" 
aria-haspopup="true" 
aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown link
    </a>
```

Comment: you're going to stuff jquery script inside a plain javascript event handler inline?

Comment: Do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap 4.0.0
since we want to simulate `.show` to hover event, it simply easy. just add all styles in `.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu` to the `:hover`. like this:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.dropdown',function(e){
  var _d=$(e.target).closest('.dropdown');
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter')_d.addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function(){
    _d.toggleClass('show', _d.is(':hover'));
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded',_d.is(':hover'));
  },300);
});

/* this is not needed, just prevents page reload when a dd link is clicked */
$('.dropdown a').on('click tap', e => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href>Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS and Desktop only solution

```
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the top solutions worked for me.

This works perfectly, keeps submenus open while browsing, add uses the native Bootstrap javascript.

```
// Mouse over
$('body').on('mouseover', '.dropdown', function(e) { 
    $(this).children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('show');
});

// Mouse leave
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.dropdown', function(e) { 
    $(this).children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Google brought me here but... The examples provided work if the dropdown menu is overlaping (at least by 1px) with its parent when show. If not, it loses focus and nothing works as intended.

Here is a working solution with jQuery and Bootstrap 4.5.2 :

```
$('li.nav-item').mouseenter(function (e) {

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        if ($(this).hasClass('dropdown')) {

            // target element containing dropdowns, show it
            $(this).addClass('show');
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show');

            // Close dropdown on mouseleave
            $('.dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function (e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $(this).removeClass('show');
            });

            // If you have a prenav above, this clears open dropdowns (since you probably will hover the nav-item going up and it will reopen its dropdown otherwise)
            $('#prenav').off().mouseenter(function (e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
            });

        } else {
            // unset open dropdowns if hover is on simple nav element
            $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just use Tao's CSS code:

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

and remove the 2px-gap between the .dropdown-toggle and the .dropdown-menu by setting its top-margin to zero:

```
.dropdown-menu { margin-top: 0!important }
```

Answer (score -1):

***(June 2020)*** I found this solution and I thought I should post it here:

Bootstrap version: ***4.3.1***

The CSS part:

```
.navbar .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
   transition: transform 0.15s linear;
}

.show.dropdown .dropdown-toggle::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

The jQuery part:

```
const $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle");
const $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
const showClass = "show";

$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  if (this.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    $dropdown.hover(
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass(showClass);
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $this.children($dropdownMenu).addClass(showClass);
      },
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass(showClass);
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        $this.children($dropdownMenu).removeClass(showClass);
      }
    );
  } else {
    $dropdown.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  }
});
```

Source: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-the-bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-work-on-hover--cms-33840

Answer (score -3):

`<div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="font-size:12px">`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.