# Bootstrap 4 navbar remove hover on dropdown menu items

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm migrating to Bootstrap 4 and currently fixing the navbar. The problem is that my dropdown menus open when I hover over them with mouse.

I need to remove the dropdown menu that is opening when an user hovers over with the mouse. I followed examples from official bootstrap website, therefore, I don't understand, is the hover option enabled by default or is there something else?

```
@helper GenerateMenuItem(MenuItem menu_item)
{
    if (!(menu_item.SubMenus.Where(it => it.AllowedRoles.Any(role => User.IsInRole(role))).Count() == 0 && menu_item.Url == null))
    {
        <li class="nav-item dropdown px-1">
            @if (menu_item.SubMenus.Where(it => it.AllowedRoles.Any(role => User.IsInRole(role))).Count() > 0)
            {
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle @menu_item.IconClass" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="@(menu_item.GetFullUrl() == null ? "javascript:" : menu_item.GetFullUrl())">@menu_item.DisplayText <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    @foreach (MenuItem submenu_item in menu_item.SubMenus.Where(it => !it.ToSort && it.AllowedRoles.Any(role => User.IsInRole(role))))
                    {
                        @GenerateMenuItem(submenu_item)
                    }
                    @foreach (MenuItem submenu_item in menu_item.SubMenus.Where(it => it.ToSort && it.AllowedRoles.Any(role => User.IsInRole(role))).OrderBy(it => it.DisplayText))
                    {
                        @GenerateMenuItem(submenu_item)
                    }
                </ul>
            }
            else
            {
                if (menu_item.GetFullUrl() == null)
                {
                    <a>@menu_item.DisplayText</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@(menu_item.GetFullUrl() == null ? "javascript:" :  menu_item.GetFullUrl())">@menu_item.DisplayText</a>
                }
            }
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: hover option is not a default of bootstrap 4 dropdown

Comment: What could cause opening dropdown items when hovering?

Comment: did you add some js for your dropdown? like dropdown events

Comment: you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183672/bootstrap-v4-navbar-dropdown-hover

Comment: I'm using Smartmenus for Bootstrap 4