# How can I make my dropdown menu links clickable?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navbar

The navbar in my theme is added by a function wp_nav_menu() in the header. 
I've modified its default behaviour to unfold drop down menu on hover as opposed to 'on click' of the main item with the following jQuery:

```
jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

The only problem remains that I don't know how to provide href="#" with some values/links for the top level items with dropdown elements. When I hover over them, the dropdown items unfold, but I'd still want them to be clickable and take the user to an url.

I know I can do it by just creating the navbar in html/css in the page templates manually but then I'd lose the possibility for the user to easily modify the menu from the WP admin dashboard.

Is it possible to keep the menu registered in WP and be able to create a clickable (href="some_page.php") dropdown menus that will unfold on hover?

EDIT:

The navbar is generated as follows:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mx-auto',
                    'fallback_cb'     => '',
                    'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
                    'depth'           => 3,
                    'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                )
            ); ?>
```

The rendered menu is:

```
 <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav mx-auto"><li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home nav-item menu-item-7"><a title="Home" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-34"><a title="About us" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/about-us/" class="nav-link">About us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-126"><a title="What&#039;s on" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/events/" class="nav-link">What&#8217;s on</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-284" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-284"><a title="Rider" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/ridehq/" class="nav-link">Rider</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-33"><a title="Join the club" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/join-the-club/" class="nav-link">Join the club</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-35"><a title="Youth" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/youth/" class="nav-link">Youth</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children nav-item menu-item-36 dropdown"><a title="Drivers" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Drivers<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class=" dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-87"><a title="Sunday Races" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/sunday-races/" class="nav-link">Sunday Races</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item menu-item-242"><a title="Cars" href="http://wp-ppp:8888/w/cars/" class="nav-link">Cars</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>                     </div><!-- .container -->
```

As you can see, wherever there's a dropdown element, the top element, eg. Drivers has the href element as "#" despite the fact that it's a custom link in the WP dashboard with a specified url.

EDIT 2:

As per the suggestion below, I've modified the bootstrap-wp-navwalker.php. In my case it was a different line. I've changed:

```
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
    $atts['href']        = '#';
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    $atts['class']       = 'nav-link dropdown-toggle';
} else {
    $atts['href']  = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
    $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
}
$atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
$attributes = '';
foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
    if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
        $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
$attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                }
            }
$item_output = $args->before;
```

to:

```
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
    $atts['href']        = $item->url;
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    $atts['class']       = 'nav-link dropdown-toggle';
} else {
    $atts['href']  = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
    $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
}
$atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
        $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
    $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
    }
            }
            $item_output = $args->before;
```

But it doesn't do anything on click (it shows the right url in the preview bar in the bottom of the browser.

Pastebin of the whole navwalker
https://pastebin.com/EDCXfSXH

Comment: Updated. Thakns

Comment: This is not WordPress related, but a bootstrap issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183672/bootstrap-v4-navbar-dropdown-hover/

Comment: Sorry, if I'm still not being clear. I know how to do it in bootstrap, etc. The problem is that once you register a navbar with WP, you have limited control over it. The href's are specified in the WP dashboard. This is absolutely a WP question - if it does not come across as such, apologies.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your question thouroughly. If you provided URL's for the top level menu items in the WP backend (instead of '#'), the top level URL's are probably being replaced by the Understrap WP Bootstrap Navwalker class. You should create your own walker, based on the existing walker, and update some of the code within this walker.

Comment: Replace '#' in line 189 by $item->url

Comment: Thanks. See Edit 2

Comment: Bootstrap stops the propagation of following the link in the click event, otherwise # would be added to the URL when clicking the dropdown toggler. Im not sure if you can undo this behaviour, but you can hack it with js. Just add a click event listener to the parent elements a tag and redirect the user using window.location to the a tags href