# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Dropdowns Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have been unable to get dropdowns in bootstrap 4 to function properly. I have searched for solutions, and while some have found them, they have not worked for me.

I have tried to both enable dropdown functionality using the template from the bootstrap documentation, as well as utilizing jquery for the dropdown to show on hover. Neither work. I have included all JS files that should be necessary.  The dropdowns not functioning was both before and after using JS for showing the menu on hover.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/nav_logo.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

JS for the dropdown onmouseover

```
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.dropdown',function(e){
  var _d=$(e.target).closest('.dropdown');
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter')_d.addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function(){
    _d.toggleClass('show', _d.is(':hover'));
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded',_d.is(':hover'));
  },300);
});
```

The current site can be found here:
http://shatteredsite.com/testing/shatteredsite.html

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap v4 has [recently changed dropdowns](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/26756), causing the [previous method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183824/1891677) to open dropdowns on hover - which you tried - no longer work.

Here's an up to date solution for v4.1.2 and above:

```js
function toggleDropdown (e) {
  let _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown'),
      _m = $('.dropdown-menu', _d);
  setTimeout(function(){
    let shouldOpen = e.type !== 'click' && _d.is(':hover');
    _m.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen);
    _d.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen);
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded', shouldOpen);
  }, e.type === 'mouseleave' ? 300 : 0);
}

$('body')
  .on('mouseenter mouseleave','.dropdown',toggleDropdown)
  .on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', toggleDropdown);
```

See it working:

```js
function toggleDropdown (e) {
  let _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown'),
      _m = $('.dropdown-menu', _d);
  setTimeout(function(){
    let shouldOpen = e.type !== 'click' && _d.is(':hover');
    _m.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen);
    _d.toggleClass('show', shouldOpen);
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr('aria-expanded', shouldOpen);
  }, e.type === 'mouseleave' ? 300 : 0);
}

$('body')
  .on('mouseenter mouseleave','.dropdown',toggleDropdown)
  .on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', toggleDropdown);

/* not needed, simply prevents reload on nav links clicks */
$('nav a').on('click tap', e => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href>Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href>Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Found [the chage](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/26756). It's part of [v4.1.2 changelist](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26423). Updated solution both here and in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

remove this from your ref code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

change to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

same goes with these script refrences

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

change to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! The JS for dropdown on hover didn't work though, so I replaced it with a CSS solution that was far simpler. Thank you!

Comment: anytime sir, do u need dropdown to work on hover with js?